# Find time taken for each line of code separately in python

Tags: python

I have `pyspark` script like below.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from datetime import datetime
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import HiveContext

conf = SparkConf()
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
sqlContext = HiveContext(sc)

hivedb='MySql'
table='abc_123'

df = sqlContext.table("{}.{}".format(hivedb,table))

# Register the Data Frame as a TempTable
df.registerTempTable('mytempTable')

#Time:
date=datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

#Find min value ID:
min_id = sqlContext.sql("select nvl(min(id),0) as minval from mytempTable").collect()[0].asDict()['minval']

sc.stop()
```

Now I want to find out time taken by each line of code separately. Something like below

```
df = sqlContext.table("{}.{}".format(hivedb,table))

Time taken for `df` to create was 10 seconds 

date=datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

Time taken for finding `date` was 1 second

min_id = sqlContext.sql("select nvl(min(id),0) as minval from mytempTable").collect()[0].asDict()['minval']

Time taken for `min_id` query to execute was 3 seconds
```

How can I achieve that.

If possible I would like to print these values as well

Comment: Get the time before calling function, get the time after function call and subtract and display it... https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.time might be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use built-in [cProfile](https://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html). If you want to visualize information, you can use [Snakeviz](https://jiffyclub.github.io/snakeviz/)

TLDR:
Run your script with `python -m cProfile [-o output_file] [-s sort_order] myscript.py` command and download Snakeviz and run `snakeviz output_file`